# Открытие и чтение файла на ассемблере

Tags: windows, ассемблер, fasm

Подскажите код или статью где описывается открытие txt файла и его вывод в консоль.

Comment: Укажите для какой операционной системы вы это хотите. От нее очень сильно зависит.

Comment: Использую Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

WinApi Функция ReadFile читает данные из файла,
Функция WriteConsole записывает символьную строку в экранный буфер консоли